# Problem with Nuxt3 + Netlify Functions + Rewrite

Tags: netlify-function, nuxtjs3

My rewrites are not working on netlify/production but I have no problems when running them locally with `netlify dev`.

The `netlify.toml` looks like this:

```
[build]
command = "npm run build"
functions = "functions"
publish = "dist"

[[redirects]]
from = '/api/*'
to = '/.netlify/functions/:splat'
force = true
status = 200
```

The `npm run build` command just calls `nuxi build`.

Now on localhost I can call `/api/something` and it works without a problem. The same call fails when deployed to netlify. It works also on production when I use `/.netlify/functions/something`.

Now the weird thing: When I remove `publish = "dist"` from the `netlify.toml` file I can call `/api/something` on production but then the nuxt code does not work, like all the pages.

I setup functions first and my desktop client is already using it which breaks when I just use `/.netlify/functions/something` because they are already using `/api/something`.

Does someone have a similar build who can help me?

Comment: Is it possible that Nuxt automatically redirects to 404 for URLs that it doesn't know?

Comment: any luck with this issue? am experiencing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

in someone is still having this issue, please the _redirects file in your public folder. the file gets copied over at build.

More info here [https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/public]